# If statement with using reference

Tags: c#, .net

I'm want to use references for System.Data.SqlServerCe or System.Data.SqlServer depending on if the user have internet connection or not.

How do i this? Can i declare some kind of global variable?

I want to do something like this:

if HASINTERNET

using System.Data.SqlServer

else

using System.Data.SqlServerCe

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your best bet there is to just use `DbConnection` or `IDbConnection`, and write a *factory method* that creates the appropriate type of connection to return (as the more abstract `DbConnection` / `IDbConnection`).

Then it will work for any connection type. Be sure to use the connection's `.CreateCommand()` method etc for creating commands.

Your `using` is then just `using System.Data;` (or `using System.Data.Common;`)

re the actual question; not really. You can do that at **compile time**, with `#if` etc - but not at runtime.